# is it possible to track user's download from App Store?

Tags: ios

our product have made some promotion, is it possible to trace the source where the user clicks the promotion url and open the App Store and download our app? if possible, how to make it?

---

maybe I made some misunderstanding, in the promotion web, I know the click can be trace by web, my question is about the process of user's opening App Store, downloading and finally opening the app. how can we make a connection between a new user and the promotion web where he comes from? does App Store support such tracking?

Comment: Maybe this question is stupid, but I don't know why this question can't be asked. it's important for iOS developer. I found some competitor make it, maybe they have a special way, but I don't know how, so I ask here

Comment: AppsFlyer is a 3rd party service that can give you the needed info.